# I can't get data from my App.config

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to get data from my App.config and searching about I have found up to 4 ways to get that data, but basically you should use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameKey/NameSetting"];
```

My App.config code is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="DXThemeManager" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="InterfazPrueba1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <DXThemeManager>
            <setting name="ApplicationThemeName" serializeAs="String">
              <value>Office2016White</value>
            </setting>
        </DXThemeManager>
    </userSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <InterfazPrueba1.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="HostBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>LOCALHOST</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="NombreBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Pruebas1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ServerBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>DESKTOP-O037RKH</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="InstanceBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="UsuarioBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>sa</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="PassBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>123</value>
            </setting>
        </InterfazPrueba1.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And the code in my class is:

```
 private void datosConexion()
    {
        server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerBD"];
        user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsuarioBD"];
        pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordBD"];
        host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostBD"];
        db= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NombreBD"];
        instance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceBD"];
        Console.WriteLine("Datos:"+server + user + pass + host + db + instance);
    }
```

All the variables have nothing.

I've tried all the ways I've seen and changed the values to keys but I just can retrieve the data...
Any idea about what is wrong or what am I doing bad?

Thank you for all the support you could give me.

Comment: The values in `applicationSettings` are accessible by the `Default` instance accessor property of the generated `InterfazPrueba1.Properties.Settings` class.

Comment: So you probably don't want to use ConfigurationManager at all.

Answer (score 3):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameSetting"]` retrives a setting that is defined in the `App.config` like this:

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      ...
   </configSections>
   <userSettings>
      ...
   </userSettings>
    <appSettings>
         <add key="NameSetting" value="123" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

If you add project specific settings under Project->Properties->Settings you can access these through a class that gets generated for you:

```
string setting = InterfazPrueba1.Properties.Settings.Default.HostBD;
```